# pomegranate Bayesian Network kills kernel

Tags: python, bayesian-networks, pomegranate

I am trying to execute the following code

```
from pomegranate import BayesianNetwork
import pandas as pd
X = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

model = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(X, algorithm='exact')
import pickle
with open('graph.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model.structure, f)
```

Where `dataframe.csv` consists in a 5627x11 dataset of discrete random variables. If I run a fraction of this dataset, the code runs, but with the entire dataset, the kernel restarts, not even starting the function `BayesianNetwork.from_samples`. What can be done to run the code in this case? Or is there a limitation to the model which cannot be changed?

Comment: What environment is this running in? (e.g. Python 3.8 with Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10)

Comment: What distributions characterize the discrete random variables? (e.g. Binary, 4 categories)

Comment: Try setting max_parents=3 for now. That will greatly speed both greedy and exact searches. Otherwise, I second @Alexander: can you post X.head() and maybe X.describe(), or attach (some of) the dataset? Pandas doesn't always infer the way you expect.